# Flask-SQAlchemy with_for_update() returning old data

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a situation in my Flask application where I need to generate increasing numbers against a consumer. For this, every consumer has a row in a separate table which holds the number generator up till now.

Since multiple requests may concurrently land on the server, I am locking the row for the update and then updating the data and committing. However, after commit, the other requests are reading the old data for the same row.

I am doing a `with_for_update` on the Model's query. The data is read, then updated, however, the second requests reads the old data. Tried by setting the DB isolation level to higher ones (`SERIALIZABLE`) but didn't work.

Sample code:

```
obj = NumberGenerator.query.filter(
    NumberGenerator.consumer_id == consumer_id
).with_for_update().first()

obj.number = obj.number + 1

db.session.add(obj)
db.session.commit()
```

The second request reads the old data. I am not able to understand why this is happening.
 I tried the same approach via `iPython` and it worked flawlessly.
Tried writing raw `MySQL` queries using `MySQLdb`, that too worked. Searched a lot on various forums (stack overflow included), package documentation and couldn't find anything.

`Flask-SQLAlchemy version: 2.3.2`

`MySQL version: 5.6`

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem. See following issue for solution https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4774

In short, the simplest way is to add `populate_existing()` to query

```py
obj = NumberGenerator.query.filter(
    NumberGenerator.consumer_id == consumer_id
).with_for_update().populate_existing()
```